# automatic loading of directory files into a python script

Tags: python, batch-processing

I have about 125 files in a directory on my linux machine. I have a script called annotate.py
which takes in one single file and adds features to a column. Essentially I am able to put the filename of one of the 125 files and run the annotate.py script, but this is not effective programming.

All the 125 files have similar format in terms of column names, and column numbers. 
So can someone please tell me how I can run annotate.py on all 125 files?

annotate.py merges two files on chromosome and position columns. However I would like input_file1 to be all the 125 files read in one at a time and merged with input_file2. 
The output should be different files each with the name of the original input file 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#python snp_search.py  input_file1 input_file2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

snp_f=pd.read_table('input_file1.txt', sep="\t", header=None)#input_file1
snp_f.columns=['chr','pos']
lsnp_f=pd.read_table('input2_snpsearch.txt', sep="\t", header=True)#input_file2
lsnp_f.columns=['snpid','chr','pos']
final_snp=pd.merge(snp_f,lsnp_f, on=['chr','pos'])
final_snp.to_csv('input_file1_annotated.txt', index=False,sep='\t')
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `os` module is your friend http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html.  The basic idea is to `import os` and use `os.listdir()` to get a list of the files in the directory you're interested in.  Something like the following would work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os


input_file2 = 'input2_snpssearch.txt'
input_dir = './' #or any other path
files = os.lisdir(input_dir) #listdir will give the file names

#you probably don't want to merge your input_file2 with itself and
#in this case it's in the same directory as the other files so
#filter it out.
files_of_interest = (f for f in files if f != input_file2)

for f in files_of_interest:
    full_name = os.path.join(input_dir, f) #necessary if input_dir is not './'
    snp_f=pd.read_table(full_name, sep="\t", header=None)#input_file1
    snp_f.columns=['chr','pos']
    lsnp_f=pd.read_table(input_file2, sep="\t", header=True)#input_file2
    lsnp_f.columns=['snpid','chr','pos']
    final_snp=pd.merge(snp_f,lsnp_f, on=['chr','pos'])
    new_fname = f.split('.')[0] + '_annotated.txt'
    final_snp.to_csv(os.path.join(input_dir, new_fname), index=False,sep='\t')
```